# Creation of a template class creates major bottleneck

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to write a scientific graph library, it works but I have some performance problems. When creating a graph I use a template class for the nodes and do something like

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < l_NodeCount; ++i) 
                m_NodeList.push_back(Node<T>(m_NodeCounter++));
```

Even though in the constructor of the node class almost nothing happens (a few variables are asigned) this part is a major bottleneck of my program (when I use over a million of nodes), especially in the debug mode it becomes too inefficient to run at all.

Is there a better way to simultaneusly create all those template classes without having to call the constructor each time or do I have to rewrite it without templates?

Comment: Templates are purely compile-time, they cannot have any impact on the execution time of your program. Changing the class template to a class would not change anything.

Comment: is m_NodeList a std::list?  have you tried a std::vector?

Comment: Have you tried reserving capacity in your vector before adding the nodes? `m_NodeList.reserve(l_NodeCount);`

Comment: 1) Have you profiled your code? 2) If you think the constructor is to blame, show us the constructor.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was indeed the push_back function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are things that happen in your code:

- as you add elements to the vector, it occasionally has to resize the internal array, which involves copying all existing elements to the new array
- the constructor is called for each element

The constructor call is unavoidable. You create a million elements, you have a million constructor calls. What you *can* change is what the constructor does.

Adding elements is obviously unavoidable too, but the copying/resizing *can* be avoided. Call `reserve` on the vector initially, to reserve enough space for all your nodes.

Depending on your compiler, optimization settings and other flags, the compiler *may* do a lot of unnecessary bounds checking and debug checks as well.

- You can disable this for the compiler (`_SECURE_SCL=0` on VS2005/2008, `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` in VS2010. I believe it's off by default in GCC, and don't know about other compilers).
- Alternatively, you can rewrite the loop to minimize the amount of debug checking that needs to be done. Using the standard library algorithms instead of a raw loop allows the library to skip most of the checks (typically, a bounds check will then be performed on the begin and the end iterator, and not on the intervening iterations, whereas on a plain loop, it'll be done every time an iterator is dereferenced)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on how I should rewrite this code? :)

Comment: Well, for example, you could use`std::generate_n`. `std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(m_NodeList), l_NodeCount, gen())`, where `gen` is a suitable generator functor, which returns the node you want to insert. But note that this is only a workaround if you run with the compiler's STL debug checking enabled. You could just disable that, since it's painfully slow in general.

Answer (score 4):

If the constructor does almost nothing, as you say, the bottleneck is most likely the allocation of new memory. The vector grows dynamically, and each time it's memory is exhausted, it will reserve new memory and copy all data there. When adding a large number of objects, this can happen very frequently, and become very expensive. This can be avoided by calling

```
m_NodeList.reserve(l_NodeCount);
```

With this call, the vector will allocate enough memory to hold `l_NodeCount` objects, and you will not have any expensive reallocations when bulk-adding the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, your bottleneck is not a template class which has nothing to do with run-time and is dealt with during compilation, but adding an element to `vector` container (you have tag "vector" in your question). You are performing A LOT of allocations using `push_back`. Try allocating required total memory right away and then fill elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the templates buy having a list of (void *) to the objects. and cast them later.
but... if you wish to have 1,000,000 instances of the node class. you will have to call 1,000,000 the node constructor.